# Will a standard wireless router support 12 wireless users?

Tags: wireless-networking, broadband

I'm having a fantasy football draft in a couple of weeks, and without thinking, I said we could do an online draft if everyone brought their laptops.  So, will my poor little Dlink G band router be able to keep up with the demand of 12 machines using it?

I'm assuming I will be telling the people to refrain from hitting Youtube, but assuming they are all playing nicely, does anyone know for sure if I'm fine or for sure if I'll have issues?

I've got Time Warner Cable 7.0Mbit in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be fine - I think they support like 250 users or so.  12 users is no problem.

Comment: Most home routers will dole out 250ish IP addresses through DHCP.  However, Im fairly positive that there is no way router can support 250 concurrent users.  And wireless would support even less concurrent connections.  Im sure that 12 wireless connections should work without issues, but the bandwidth will be severely limited.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Most home routers can easily take that many users (provided they aren't all surfing youtube.)